# Cargar enteros como array

Tags: json, nodejs, postgresql, sequelize

Estoy trabajando en un servidor backend con NodeJS, Sequelize y PostgreSQL, y tengo dos tablas: **Roles** y **Usuarios** en mi BD donde intento cargar los roles como un array para así poder asignar más de un rol a un usuario. Es posible realizar este tipo de insert?

**Tabla rol**

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
id SERIAL,
descripcion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NULL,
updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NULL,
CONSTRAINT roles_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

**Tabla usuarios**

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
id SERIAL,
rol_id INTEGER,
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NULL,
updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NULL,
CONSTRAINT usuarios_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT roles_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES roles(id));
```

Comment: quieres ayuda con una SQL INSERT , o un script JS? (Puedes agregar un ejemplo del JSON)

Comment: Disculpa, lo he expresado mal... Lo que quiero hacer es cargar en la tabla usuario los roles_id como un array
E.j: insert into usuario( rol_id, ... )  values ( [1, 3], ... )

Answer (score 0):

Para poder guardar los roles del usuario como un arreglo, tienes que definir la columna como de tipo arreglo (en este caso un arreglo de enteros `INTEGER[]`).

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
id SERIAL,
roles_ids INTEGER[],
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NULL,
updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NULL,
CONSTRAINT usuarios_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));

-- INSERT QUERIES:

INSERT INTO usuarios (..., roles_ids ,...) VALUES (..., ARRAY[1, 2], ...);

-- ó

INSERT INTO usuarios (..., roles_ids ,...) VALUES (..., '{1, 2}', ...);
```

El problema es que nativamente no vas a poder definir la llaves foraneas (Foreign Key) sobre el arreglo de roles (tendrías que encargarte tu de chequear la integridad referencial). Si hay algunas extensiones para postresql que permiten hacerlo, pero tendrías que instalarlas aparte.

Igulamente creo que este no es el mejor enfoque. Yo crearía una nueva tabla usuarios_roles para almacenar los roles que tiene seteados cada usuario (de esta forma vas a poder definir las Foreign Keys sin problemas, además creo te va a simplificar las queries).

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios_roles(
usuario_id INTEGER,
rol_id INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT usuarios_roles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (usuario_id, rol_id),
CONSTRAINT roles_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES roles(id),
CONSTRAINT usuario_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya el compañero nachospiu explicó que si es posible, sin embargo por cuestiones de diseño el comportamiento entre esas dos tablas representa una relación donde múltiples usuarios puede tener múltiples roles es decir muchos a muchos esto según las buenas prácticas esto se resuelve con una nueva tabla donde ambas tablas ceden su llave primaria para que sean relacionadas.